# Error creating python application with MATLAB code (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

Tags: python, matlab, ubuntu

I read the following instructions in order to create a python application using matlab code: [Create a Python Application with MATLAB Code](https://la.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-python-application-with-matlab-code.html)

Everything is ok, when I execute the command`python setup.py install` the following message shows up:

```
root@david:/home/david/Desktop/Matrices_Clifford/for_redistribution_files_only# python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Matrices_Clifford
copying Matrices_Clifford/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Matrices_Clifford
copying Matrices_Clifford/Matrices_Clifford.ctf -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Matrices_Clifford
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Matrices_Clifford
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Matrices_Clifford/Matrices_Clifford.ctf -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Matrices_Clifford
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Matrices_Clifford/__init__.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Matrices_Clifford
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Matrices_Clifford/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matlabruntimeforpython-R2017a.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matlabruntimeforpython-R2017a.egg-info
removing 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7' (and everything under it)
'build/bdist.linux-x86_64' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
removing 'build'
```

Then, when I try to import Matrices_Clifford there is an error:

```
import Matrices_Clifford
    Exception caught during initialization of Python interface. Details: On Linux, you must set the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to a non-empty string. For more details, see the package documentation.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "Matrices_Clifford/__init__.py", line 276, in <module>
        _pir.get_paths_from_os()
      File "Matrices_Clifford/__init__.py", line 171, in get_paths_from_os
        friendly_os_name, self.path_var, 'For more details, see the package documentation.'))
    RuntimeError: On Linux, you must set the environment variable "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to a non-empty string. For more details, see the package documentation.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite self-explanatory. The environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` must be defined so that the operating system knows the location of the libraries. Use the [setenv command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setenv.3.html) to define it properly, as follows:

```
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH path/to/libraries
```

It seems that [this link](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/set-run-time-library-path-on-linux-systems.html) can point you to the right path (no pun intended) and that the required location is in the form of `matlabroot/bin/glnxa64:matlabroot/sys/os/glnxa64`.

Comment: For me (MATLAB R2022a Linux) it was `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MATLABROOT/runtime/glnxa64"`